# Help drawing myoglobine scheme with chemfig

Tags: chemfig

Can someone help me to get a result like this with `chemfig` (or something else)?

[image]

i know to get this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\chemname{\chemfig{Fe^{2+}(-[::90]G)(-[::-90]G)(-[::35]\ce{N-})(-  [::-35]N)(-[::-145]\ce{^{-}N})(-[::145]\ce{N})}}{Myoglobin}
\end{document}
```

how can i get the dashed bond and the second naming?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overall structure is a simple table, so a `tabular` should do fine

```
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  \chemfig{...} & ... \\
  Myoglobin & ... \\
  Fleischfarbe \\
  purpurrot & ... 
\end{tabular}
```

As for the chemical formulas: using the bonds optional parameters they are quite easy with `chemfig`. Here is an example for one of the structures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  Fe|^{2+}
    (-[1,,1,,very thick]N^{-})
    (-[2,,1]G)
    (-[3,,1,,very thick,dotted]N)
    (-[5,,1,2,very thick]^{-}|N)
    (-[6,,1]NO)
    (-[7,,1,,very thick,dotted]N)
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The parameters are

```
<bond>[<angle>,<length factor>,<departure atom>,<arrival atom>,<tikz options>]
```

Comment: @Jaska this is controlled by a parameter *bond offset*. Search the `chemfig` manual for `\setbondoffset`…